# Issue with installing packages on virtual environment created by anaconda

Tags: python, linux, networking, pip, anaconda

I installed anaconda on a sandbox in my work and trying to install tensorflow. I ran below command and run into issue.

```
(venv) [root@box4 venv]# pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.4.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
Collecting tensorflow-gpu==1.4.0 from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.4.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f6304ba9e80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.4.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl 
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f6304ba9f28>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.4.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f6304b5c048>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.4.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
^COperation cancelled by user
```

I tried below command to check if internet is available on that box

```
(venv) [root@gmc4bayer venv]# ping storage.googleapis.com
PING storage.l.googleusercontent.com (172.217.12.48) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- storage.l.googleusercontent.com ping statistics ---
19 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 17999ms
```

I am trying to find  dest IP and any port(s) required so that I can ask my network admin to whitelist it. I might have to install lot of other packages. Do I have to find IPs for all those websites also and whitelist them? Wondering if there is a clean and easy way to resolve this issue

Any one ran into this issue?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Anaconda Navigator to install packages.